# Mikrotik и пул белых ip

Tags: маршрутизация, mikrotik, маршрутизатор

Здравствуйте stackoverflowовцы. Подскажите пожалуйста как пробросить белый ip в локалку? суть проблемы такова: 
был свитч с входом оптики и выход rj-45, на несколько серверов уходила витая пара с белыми ip, и в сеть офиса уходил белый ip. Заменили оборудование на mikrotik с sfp портом и воткнули напрямую в него. Для mikrotik задали ip xxx.xxx.xxx.210. Для серверов пробовал сделать бридж, воткнуть сервер в 10й порт и добавить в ip>addresses белый ip для бриджа xxx.xxx.xxx.213 но тогда отваливается xxx.xxx.xxx.210 а xxx.xxx.xxx.213 работает. 
Настраивать на серверах локальный ip и пробрасывать на белые ip нельзя так как оборудование чужое и в него нельзя лезть. Как можно реализовать подскажите пожалуйста? mikrotik 1036-12-4s

Comment: Думаю не надо поднимать на микротике 213 адрес. По идее надо снять 210 адрес с физического интерфейса и поставить его на бридже

Comment: то есть все белые ip через бридж?

Comment: да. не знаю как микротик, но linux бы был не очень доволен, если одна и та же подсеть фактически находилась на двух разных устройствах, пришлось бы долго танцевать с бубном вокруг таблиц маршрутизации (нескольких)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю что как-то так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Тогда и у серверов остаются свои адреса и у роутера свой белый адрес. Адреса на физические интерфейсы вешать не надо.

Comment: Попробовал как вы порекомендовали но появилась новая проблема. Пингуется из внешней но из локалки никак во внешнюю сеть, не получают устройства инета, хотя микротик во внешку пингует /tool ping. Сделал немного не так, разделил микротик на sfp+eth1-eth6 сделал из них бридж-свитч(в конфиге бридж с провайдером, при подключении девайсов с 1го до 6го порта(с конфигом белых IP) получают инет и работают отлично). И бридж-роутер с 7го до 12го порта. Назначил бридж-роутеру ip белый и ip для локалки. Но проблема та же.. Снова пинг к ip офисому проходит а из офиса во внешнюю сеть не пингует..

Comment: остальные настройки надо видеть: маршрут по умолчанию, разрешения для пересылки пакетов из локалки в инет, ну и nat на интерфейсе bridge1